# How to read local text file and put data in an array to prepare playlist in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, file, arraylist

As you can see that in this player I want make an array which can fetch list of video paths from a locally stored text file in the internal memory of the device.As u can see in the below code that I'm using `.add` to store the path in the array.Please tell me a code to read the text file and put it into the array named `videoList`.Thanks in advance

```
public class AttractLoopMain extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener,
    SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private ArrayList<String> videoList = new ArrayList<String>();
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private int currentVideo = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.attract_loop);




    //videoList.add("/mnt/sdcard/a1.mp4");
    //videoList.add("/mnt/sdcard/a2.mp4");
    //videoList.add("/sdcard/download/test9-3.m4v");

    SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    holder = surface.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    currentVideo = 0;

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    finish();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: Use a FileReader in combination with a BufferedReader to read line by line

Comment: Can you please edit my code above...please Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't work this way. Please read the documentation, try to write the code yourself and if you have particular problems you can ask again

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("filepath"));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (s.hasNext()){
    list.add(s.next());
}
s.close();
```

Comment: This will fail if the filename contains spaces

Comment: there are lot of ways around it.. 
may be you can use 
    String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path);

Comment: @blganesh101 it is showing unhandeled exception type filenotfound

Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("/mnt/sdcard/a1.mp4"));

Comment: File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourFile = new File(dir, "path/to/the/file/inside/the/sdcard.ext");

Comment: @blganesh101 Sir how to pass yourfile in the code above in scanner...i m doing like this and showing error..thnks a lot sir
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
  File yourFile = new File(dir, "/mnt/sdcard/pl.txt");
  Scanner s = new Scanner( yourFile);
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (s.hasNext()){
      videoList.add(s.next());
  }
  s.close();